# How to migrate a Windows Workflow Foundation Solution to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am currently looking to migrate to Visual Studio 2019. One of our solutions uses Windows Workflow Foundation technology. After installing VS 2019 the solution will not load and states "needs migration"

I have followed the steps detailed here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/workflow-designer/developing-applications-with-the-workflow-designer?view=vs-2019

Looking for some advice as to else the issie may be?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. This might be better question for StackOverflow as it relates to coding technologies.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Wasn't sure if that was the right forum as it does not directly relate to code, but i'll put it out there, thanks